# Detecting a record that includes a certain value, when it occurs after a record with a different value in that column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a table that looks kind of like this.

```
ID   Condition   Date
11       A       03/12
11       B       03/14
12       A       03/12
12       B       03/11  
13       A       03/14
14       B       03/10
```

I'm trying to get a count of all IDs listed as Condition A, but excluding IDs that have a Condition B occurring after the A. If the B comes *before* the A, I'll count the ID as normal. For example, the table above would get me an ID count of 2 (#12 and #13), with ID #11 excluded because it has a B coming after an A, and ID #14 excluded because it's not an A.

Figuring out how to detect the specific and sole condition of an ID with a B coming after the same ID with an A, and then excluding it without impacting the other A entries, is giving me trouble. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You can summarize the data by id and then count.  Here is a pretty simple method:

```
select count(*)
from (select id,
             max(case when condition = 'A' then date end) as date_a,
             max(case when condition = 'B' then date end) as date_b
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
where (date_a > date_b) or
      (date_a is not null and date_b is null);
```

You could also write what I think is a more complicated version using `not exists`:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where t.condition = 'A' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.condition = 'B' and
                        t2.date > t.date
                 );
```